# How can I authenticate user using JWT token in meteor and get details of user in Meteor.user()?

Tags: meteor, jwt, single-sign-on

My application has JWT token generated for users from some third party application.

When I decode it using jwt.io, it decodes correctly.

I need token authentication for meteor application using meteor login with token.

My code snippet is as below:

```
 Meteor.loginWithToken(token, (err) => {
   if(err){
     console.log("loginwithtoken Err", err);
   }else{
     console.log("Login successful");
     console.log("current user is ", Meteor.user());
   }
 });
```

Always I am getting error as below:

[image]

How can I log in a user here so that all the user details ill be available in Meteor.user() all over the application? Is it a right way I am doing?

Comment: `My application has JWT token generated for users` how did you generate the token? Please add the code. `Always I am getting error here.` please add the errors but not as screenshot but as formatted text / code.